# Symfony Custom Announce Search with array entity

Tags: php, arrays, forms, symfony

I'm making an announcements website and I am trying to make a research form for only showing announcements that I choose.

For example, there is a form where people can mark roles for searching only on the announcements with that chosen role.

**Example:**

There are 4 buttons:

- Coach,
- Shooter,
- Goalkeeper,
- Winger

I select Coach and Shooter. I would like to see only announcements with players who have both the Coach and Shooter role (each player can have many different roles).

In my entity "poste" which is an array, there are all the different roles of what he can play.

**Example:**

```
mypost = $announce->getPoste();
// mypost[0] will have coach
// mypost[1] will have shooter
```

I try a lot of things but it never works with this entity type.

### Controller:

```
$repository = $this
    ->getDoctrine()
    ->getManager()
    ->getRepository('PlatformBundle:Announce');

$criteria2 = $announce->getPoste();

$criteria = array_filter(array(
    'game'     => $game, // example: football
    'region'   => $announce->getRegion(), //example: Europe
    'language' => $announce->getLanguage(), //example: FR
    'poste'    => $announce->getPoste(), //example: Goalkeeper, Shooter, Coatch
    'level'    => $announce->getLevel() //example: Pro
));

$announces = $repository->findBy($criteria);
<!-- It's work for everything but not for getPoste -->

$announces = $repository->findByPoste($criteria2);
<!-- no match -->
```

I try a lot of things, like creating a repository function and making a custom SQL/DQL function but it's still doesn't work. I tried to search on Google for **Symfony 3 findBy() array parameters" but I haven't found anything for my example.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What do you mean by `it never works`? What specifically isn't working? What output are you getting? Are you getting no output? Askew output? Error messages?

Comment: Hello,I Actually if i use $announces = $repository->findBy($criteria); Everythin work with all the variable, game, level, region, language but it's doesn't match with poste and i don't find any announce.

Comment: In my _profiler, i can check the parameter and there is no problem, every parameters are inside the variable. Parameters: [ 0 => football, 1 =>Europe, 2 => FR, 3 => [ 0 => coatch, 1 => shooter ], 4 => pro ]

Comment: Var_dump of $criteria: C:\wamp64\www\Wolk\src\Wolk\PlatformBundle\Controller\Announ‌​ceController.php:73: array (size=5) 'game' => string 'football' (length=8) 'region' => string 'America' (length=7) 'language' => string 'FR' (length=2) 'poste' => array (size=2) 0 => string 'coatch' (length=6) 1 => string 'shooter' (length=7) 'level' => string 'Pro' (length=3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Doctrine `findBy()` method works with the associative array as a param. If you want restrict any field with by multiple values, then you have to use an array of values as the particular column criteria.

For example in your case:

```
$criteria = array(
    'game' => $game,
    'region' => $region,
    ...
    'poste' => array('Coatch', 'Shooter', ...),
    ...
);
```

So, the `getPoste()` method of your `Announce` class has to return an array with the desired players posts, respectively the values which you have stored in the DB.

**EDIT**

In case you have the property of array type, you have to create custom query via doctrine queryBuilder. Create the repository for the Announce entity and there you can make own methods for getting data. Check the example bellow, for your particular case(code not tested, so minor tweaks would be required).

```
class AnnounceRepository extends ORM\EntityRepository
{
    ...
    ...

    public function findAnnouncesByCriteria($game, $region, $language, $poste, $level)
    {
        $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('user')
            ->from('PlatformBundle\Announce', 'announce');

        if ($game!== null) {
            $qb->andWhere('announce.game = \''.$game.'\'');

        }

        ...
        ...

        if ($poste!== null) {
            foreach($poste as $itm)
                $qb->andWhere('announce.poste like \'%'.$itm.'%\'' );
        }

        ...
        ...

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, i already have a column in my entity announce who contain this:
  /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="poste", type="array")
     */
    private $poste; And in my sql database, there are all the different role in a array, goolkeeper etc. And when i write $criteria2 = $announce->getPoste(); My variable $criteria2 contains all the different role but it's doesn't match and i don't see any announce when i test it.

Comment: What returns the $announce->getPoste(), or please `var_dump($criteria2);` respectively.

Comment: In my _profiler, i can check the parameter and there is no problem, every parameters are inside the sql variable. Parameters: [ 0 => football, 1 =>Europe, 2 => FR, 3 => [ 0 => coatch, 1 => shooter ], 4 => pro ]

Comment: So your $criteria array contains the values, but it's key are missing. The $criteria should look like `[ game  => football, region => europe, language => FR, poste => [ 0 => coatch, 1 => shooter ], level => pro ]` or the $criteria2 from your example should look like `[ poste => [ 0 => coatch, 1 => shooter ] ]`

Comment: it's working for all the different variable, game, region, language and level with the key missing but not for poste.

Comment: Var_dump of $criteria: C:\wamp64\www\Wolk\src\Wolk\PlatformBundle\Controller\AnnounceController.php:73:
array (size=5)
  'game' => string 'football' (length=8)
  'region' => string 'America' (length=7)
  'language' => string 'FR' (length=2)
  'poste' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'coatch' (length=6)
      1 => string 'shooter' (length=7)
  'level' => string 'Pro' (length=3)

Comment: Looks ok to me, it should work... Can you check the result of `$repository->findBy(array('poste' => array('coatch', 'shooter')))`

Comment: No match x/ and same thing with only one role $repository->findBy(array('poste' => array('shooter'))

Comment: And the data in the DB matches (values vs ids, lowercase vs uppercase vs collation settings, etc.)?

Comment: can you explain yourself? I try to lowercase of everything still no working. What is values vs ids and collation settings?

Comment: I mean how does the data in the DB look like vs what is used as query params? Can you post code of the PlatformBundle:Announce class and  some data sample from the db table where it's stored?

Comment: In my database, there is a column in announce named "poste", who is a DC2Type:Array. In each announce there are something like this inside: a:2:{i:0;s:6:"coatch";i:1;s:7:"shooter";}

Comment: Aaaha, in that case the Doctrine findBy() mathod doesn't work. I solved such a case in my previous project by custom query. I'm going to alter the original answer.

Comment: do you find it? :)

Comment: Don't understand - what do you mean?